# Using an If Then with multiple Or operators for Date

Tags: vba, excel

Im trying to create vba coding for an If function with multiple Or operators.

I want it to search the entire workbook in range C10 and C12. If it finds "No" in C10, or if the date matches or the day has passed the date in C12, I want it to return the sheet name to range A8. However, I don't want it to return if C12 does not have a date.

This is what I have so far:

```
Dim MRow As Long
MRow = 8
With wsAddPatient
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Range("C10").Value = "No" Or ws.Range("C12").Value = Date And ws.Range("C12").Value > 0 Then
            .Cells(MRow, 1).Value = ws.Name
            MRow = MRow + 1
        End If
    Next
End With
```

Update Final:

```
Dim MRow As Long
MRow = 8
With wsAddPatient
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
       If (ws.Range("C10").Value = "No" _
            Or (ws.Range("C12").Value <= Date) _
            And ws.Range("C12").Value > 0) Then
            .Cells(MRow, 1).Value = ws.Name
            MRow = MRow + 1
        End If
    Next
End With
```

Comment: Where is the error? When you say the date matches, do you mean today's date?

Comment: The error is that I can't get it to return values for a past date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean today's date has been reached or passed in C12;

```
If (ws.Range("C10").Value = "No" _
Or ws.Range("C12").Value <= Date) _
And IsDate (ws.Range("C12").Value) Then
```

Also, I'd use the `with` block to get rid of `ws` not `wsAddPatient` because you use the latter only once, so it doesn't save you any code at all. But it would be helpful for `ws`:

```
Dim MRow As Long
MRow = 8
With ws
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If (.Range("C10").Value = "No" _
        Or .Range("C12").Value >= Date) _
        And IsDate (ws.Range("C12").Value) Then
            AddPatient.Cells(MRow, 1).Value = .Name
            MRow = MRow + 1
        End If
    Next
End With
```

Comment: After a slight modification, I was able to get it. Thanks for your help!